# The filter "truncate" (of twig) does not exist in a view of a vendor bundle

Tags: symfony, twig, bundle, composer-php, twig-extension

I am trying to use the bundle JMS Translation but I have this error. It is I guess because my version of twig is not the same the one of the bundle? What to do?

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "The filter "truncate" does not exist in "...\vendor\jms\translation-bundle\JMS\TranslationBundle/Resources/views/Translate/messages.html.twig" at line 14" at ...\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\ExpressionParser.php line 588
```

Here is my requirement in composer.json:

```
 "require": {
        ...
        "twig/extensions": "~1.2.0",
```

Here is what is in the composer of JMS Translation:

```
"conflict": {
    "twig/twig": "1.10.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "*",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18):

Save this in a txt file and use ever!

### For Twig extensions (truncate & wordwrap)

```
composer require twig/extensions
```

### after that you have two ways...

```
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text());
```

### Or include in services.yml

```
services:
    twig.extension.text:
            class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
            tags:
                - { name: twig.extension }
```

### For Symfony 4

#### in the file 'config/packages/twig_extensions.yaml'

```
Uncomment any lines below to activate that Twig extension
Twig\Extensions\ArrayExtension: null
Twig\Extensions\DateExtension: null
Twig\Extensions\IntlExtension: null
Twig\Extensions\TextExtension: null
```

Answer (score 5):

Although when I had installed it, it worked fine, now, it needs this:

```
services:
    twig.extension.text:
           class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
           tags:
               - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Addid this only changed the error message to be more general, saying `The filter "translate" does not exist` instead of `.. exist in ...` :-(

Answer (score 1):

With symfony 4 you can use `twig extra`   https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/u.html

Comment: Yes. composer require twig/string-extra

Answer (score 1):

This solution works fine for me :

1. `$ composer require -W twig/extensions`
2. Uncomment any lines below to activate that Twig extension:

```
Twig\Extensions\ArrayExtension: null  
Twig\Extensions\DateExtension: null  
Twig\Extensions\IntlExtension: null  
Twig\Extensions\TextExtension: null
```